# Rails 3 one-to-many relationship question - how to return column name value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a one-tomany relationship with 2 tables as follows:

Models:

```
class MediaType < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :media
end

class Media < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :media_types
end
```

SQL for simplicity sake are:

```
create_table :media do |t|
  t.string "name", :limit => 255
  t.integer "media_type_id"
end

create_table :media_types do |t|
  t.string "name", :limit => 255
end
```

Once I insert a Media record relating to a media_type_id, how do I pull back the media_type.name value related to the media record?

I blindly tried:

```
media = Media.find(1)
media.media_type_id.name
```

But that didn't work of course. Is my SQL not Rails standards possibly?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you idea: media_type has many medias, but every media has only one media_type

You need another models:

```
class MediaType < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :medias
end

class Media < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :media_type
end
```

And

```
media = Media.find(1)
media.media_type.name
```

give you name

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm still new to Raails :) Does MediaType need to be "has_many :medias"? I also tried "has_many :media" with the "s" and that seems to work. What's the difference?

Comment: It's agreements, one of many in Rails. If "has_many" or "has_and_belongs_to_many", you need plural form of word in common (In most of case it does add 's' in the end of word, but sometimes, for example, 'media' does not look very well)
    `has_many :subscribers
    has_many :users
    has_many :films`
but has_many :media
Try look 'media'.pluralize and 'user'.pluralize in Rails console, you can see, how Rails pluralize words

Answer (score 0):

It seems that media `has_many` media_types.

In that case you would create `media_id` column in `media_types` table, but you did it other way around.

You will then approach each relation by

```
types = Media.media_types
```

to get the media_types that the Media has, and

```
media = MediaType.media
```

to get the media that mediatype belongs to.